# Laravel My session is not available in other controller function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a issue , I am creating session but when we access session in another controller,

so the session variable not found there

Route

```
Route::get('entry1', 'TestController@entry1');
Route::get('entry2', 'TestController@entry2');
```

Controller function

```
public function entry1(Request $request)
{
Session::put('username', 'adminTest');
echo Session::get('username');
}
public function entry2(Request $request)
{
echo Session::get('username');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

To set value in session :

```
Session(['sessionId' => $sessionId]);
```

To get value from session

```
$sessionId = Session('sessionId');
```

Comment: Not work, My project have differest issue, But i want to debug why my session expiring.